# How to generate a CSV file with jinja2 template with dict elements in Ansible?

Tags: linux, csv, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to generate a CSV output file with the following template:
Hostname;Login;UID;GID;Comments;SUDO Enabled;Last_Login_Date

This task has to check this information for every user with UID >= 1000 based on info located at /etc/passwd. The comments is the same Comments field in /etc/passwd. If an user has SUDO privileges, it has to show just YES or NO. For the Last_Login_Date, if the user has never logged to this system, it should show N/A.

For this task, I have come with an Ansible playbook solution but I can't figure out how to fix the following error when creating the CSV file.

The playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Check User List
      shell:
        cmd: |
           awk -F ':' '{ if ($3 >= 999 && $7 != "/sbin/nologin") print $1 }' /etc/passwd
      register: user_list_result

    - name: Get info on /etc/passwd
      ansible.builtin.shell: "grep ^{{ item }}: /etc/passwd"
      loop: "{{ user_list_result.stdout_lines }}"
      register: user_info_results

    - name: Check SUDO Privileges
      ansible.builtin.shell: "sudo -U {{ item.item }} -l | grep -q '(ALL) ALL' && echo 'YES' || echo 'NO'"
      loop: "{{ user_info_results.results }}"
      register: sudo_status_results

    - name: Check Last Login Date
      ansible.builtin.shell: "lastlog -u {{ item.item }} | awk 'NR==2 { print $4 }'"
      loop: "{{ user_info_results.results }}"
      register: last_login_results

    - name: Build CSV File
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "userlist_template.j2"
        dest: "output.csv"
      vars:
        user_info_results: "{{ user_info_results.results }}"
        sudo_status_results: "{{ sudo_status_results.results }}"
        last_login_results: "{{ last_login_results.results }}"
```

And I have come to this  Jinja2 template:

```
Hostname;Login;UID;GID;Comments;SUDO Enabled;Last_Login_Date
{% for user_info in user_info_results %}
{{ inventory_hostname }};{{ user_info['item'] }};{{ user_info.stdout.split(':')[2] }};{{ user_info.stdout.split(':')[3] }};{{ user_info.stdout.split(':')[4] }};{{ sudo_status_results[loop.index0].stdout }};{{ last_login_results[loop.index0].stdout | default('N/A') }}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I run this playbook the following error occurs:

```
The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'str object' has no attribute 'item'
```

It seems that Ansible is checking for a string object but it's a dict object. How can I achieve the proposed file?

Comment: `{{ user_info['item'] }}` this is what it's referring to. Your `Get info on /etc/passwd` task should be returning only a list of user strings so there would be no `['item']` attribute to index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're not on Mac OS, I'd suggest you to use [`getent`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html) module instead of parsing the files manually.

Now to the template structure. If we simplify it for debugging purposes, we'll see that the `user_info_results` variable doesn't seem to have the structure you would expect:

```
Hostname;Login;UID;GID;Comments;SUDO Enabled;Last_Login_Date
{% for user_info in user_info_results %}
{{ inventory_hostname }};{{ user_info }}
{% endfor %}
```

```
Hostname;Login;UID;GID;Comments;SUDO Enabled;Last_Login_Date
localhost;results;
localhost;skipped;
localhost;changed;
localhost;msg;
```

So, using the nested `results` object of your variables fixes the template:

```
Hostname;Login;UID;GID;Comments;SUDO Enabled;Last_Login_Date
{% for user_info in user_info_results.results %}
{{ inventory_hostname }};{{ user_info['item'] }};{{ user_info.stdout.split(':')[2] }};{{ user_info.stdout.split(':')[3] }};{{ user_info.stdout.split(':')[4] }};{{ sudo_status_results.results[loop.index0].stdout }};{{ last_login_results.results[loop.index0].stdout | default('N/A') }}
{% endfor %}
```

I decreased the UID to 280 for testing because I don't have any UIDs >= 1000 locally:

```
Hostname;Login;UID;GID;Comments;SUDO Enabled;Last_Login_Date
localhost;_coreml;280;280;CoreML Services;NO;
localhost;_sntpd;281;281;SNTP Server Daemon;NO;
localhost;_trustd;282;282;trustd;NO;
localhost;_darwindaemon;284;284;Darwin Daemon;NO;
localhost;_notification_proxy;285;285;Notification Proxy;NO;
localhost;_oahd;441;441;OAH Daemon;NO;
```

Why does it happen?
While it looks kind of surprising, it's documented:
[the registered variables have higher precedence than task vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

If we override the variables using `set_facts` instead, your old template works as you expect:

```yaml
    - name: Override the variables
      set_fact:
        user_info_results: "{{ user_info_results.results }}"
        sudo_status_results: "{{ sudo_status_results.results }}"
        last_login_results: "{{ last_login_results.results }}"

    - name: Build CSV File
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "userlist_template.j2"
        dest: "output.csv"
```

Comment: "_I'd suggest you to use `getent` module instead of parsing the files manually._", indeed. And how to do it according the requirement is already shown under [Get users using `getent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980394/6771046) and [Compare attribute to a number.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60751994/6771046).

Comment: Thank you for your time and for clarifying this question for me. The suggested change to the template worked.

Comment: I noticed that only the last server is registered, the loop is not storing all servers. What could be incorrect, the jinja template?

Answer (score 0):

"*I'd suggest you to use `getent` module instead of parsing the files manually*", indeed. And how to do it according the requirement is already shown under [Get users using `getent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980394/6771046) and [Compare attribute to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60751994/6771046).

Based on the mentioned examples, a minimal playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    users_nologin: "{{ getent_passwd | dict2items |
                       selectattr('value', 'contains', '/sbin/nologin') |
                       map(attribute='key') }}"

    users_highid: "{{ getent_passwd | dict2items |
                      json_query('[?to_number(value[1]) >= `1000`].key') }}"

  tasks:

  - getent:
      database: passwd
      split: ':'

  - debug:
      var: users_nologin | to_yaml

  - debug:
      var: users_highid | to_yaml

  - name: Check SUDO Privileges
    shell:
      cmd: "sudo -U {{ item }} -l | grep -q '(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' && echo 'YES' || echo 'NO'"
      warn: false
    loop: "{{ users_highid }}"
    register: privileges

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.item }}"
    loop: "{{ privileges.results }}"

  - name: Check Last Login Date
    shell:
      cmd: "lastlog -u {{ item }} | tail -n +2 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4-"
    loop: "{{ users_highid }}"
    register: lastlogin

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.item }}"
    loop: "{{ lastlogin.results }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [test] *********************************************************************

TASK [getent] *******************************************************************
ok: [two.example.com]
ok: [one.example.com]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  users_nologin | to_yaml: |-
    [operator, polkitd, mail, tcpdump, tss, bin, sssd, ntp, nobody, daemon, sshd,
      systemd-network, postfix, dbus]
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  users_nologin | to_yaml: |-
    [operator, polkitd, mail, tcpdump, tss, bin, sssd, ntp, nobody, daemon, sshd,
      systemd-network, postfix, dbus]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [two.example.com] =>
  users_highid | to_yaml: |-
    []
ok: [one.example.com] =>
  users_highid | to_yaml: |-
    [t-ansible]

TASK [Check SUDO Privileges] ****************************************************
changed: [one.example.com] => (item=t-ansible)

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [one.example.com] => (item=t-ansible) =>
  msg: 'NO'

TASK [Check Last Login Date] ****************************************************
changed: [one.example.com] => (item=t-ansible)

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [one.example.com] => (item=t-ansible) =>
  msg: Mon Jan 29 09:00:00 +0100 2024
```

Keep in mind that [Getent Group or Passwd might show only local users](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3515891) if connected to a domain in example via `sssd` and depending on the configuration.